# ¿Como incluir un campo annotate en filter Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Estoy intentando hacer un filtro con el campo `total_clasificacion`, pero
me da el siguiente error.

> NameError: name total_clasificacion is not defined

```
listado_facturas = Clasificacion.objects.filter(
    Q(factura__cliente=1)&
    Q(factura__trafico__tipo_operacion=1)&
    Q(factura__trafico__modal=1) &
    Q(factura__trafico__fecha_cruce=None))\
.order_by().values('factura__valor_factura','factura__id')\
.annotate(total_clasificacion = Sum('total'))\
.filter(factura__valor_factura=total_clasificacion)

print(listado_facturas)
```

¿Como puedo hacer referencia al campo `total_clasificacion` dentro del `filter`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intenta con la funcion [`F()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.10/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F
listado_facturas = Clasificacion.objects.filter(
    Q(factura__cliente=1)&
    Q(factura__trafico__tipo_operacion=1)&
    Q(factura__trafico__modal=1) &
    Q(factura__trafico__fecha_cruce=None))\
.order_by().values('factura__valor_factura','factura__id')\
.annotate(total_clasificacion = Sum('total'))\
.filter(factura__valor_factura=F('total_clasificacion'))

print(listado_facturas)
```